# ; after end What effect does it have on performance?

Tags: julia

```
       function fill_twos!(a)
           for i = eachindex(a)
               a[i] = 2
           end
       end;
```

function from [JULIA DOC](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/performance-tips/)
It is also available in some places after Struct

Comment: AFAIK, it has no effect on performance at all

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `;` doesn't have any effect on performance. The example code in the Julia manual uses it only to reduce unnecessary output in the code segments.

Normally, whatever code you type in the REPL, the result of it gets printed by the REPL. If you want your code to get evaluated, but its result not be printed out, you can add a semicolon at the end of it.

```
julia> x = pi
π = 3.1415926535897...

julia> x = pi;
```

Both the above lines assign the value of `pi` to `x`, but the second one doesn't print the result of that evaluation because it ends in a semicolon. Similarly, when you type out a function in the REPL:

```
julia> function fill_twos!(a)
         for i = eachindex(a)
           a[i] = 2
         end
       end
fill_twos! (generic function with 1 method)
```

That last line is the output from defining your function. In the example code segments, this would just be clutter that takes up extra space, if it was printed out for every function/method definition. And so, they're suppressing that output using the semicolon.

It has no effect on performance or any other aspect of the function execution.